# Want to remove Snip and Sketch from PrintScreen key

Tags: windows-10

Followed https://com-puterworks.com/remove_apps.html by launching PowerShell as admin and entering
Get-AppxPackage *Microsoft.ScreenSketch* | Remove-AppxPackage

but PrintScreen still starts Snip and sketch. A reboot of the OS showed PrintScreen still invokes it.

How do I release PrintScreen so I can use it with Greenshot  ?

Windows 10, version 1909 , build 18363.778

Comment: Is the shortcut enabled in settings?

Comment: Go to Settings > Ease of Access > Interaction > Keyboard, and scroll down to "Print Screen shortcut". Here you can find the toggle option 'Use the PrtScn button to open snipping' slider to 'Off'.

Answer (score 2):

*This seems obvious so it's likely that you've already tried it.*

There is an option to launch Snip and Sketch from a PrintScreen press in the Settings app. Go to **Ease of Access** > **Interaction** > **Keyboard**, and scroll down to "Print Screen shortcut". Toggle the 'Use the PrtScn button to open snipping' slider to 'Off'.

Follow the advice and restart your computer.

[image: This is where the option is]

Comment: If only they would also let us disable Win-Alt-S as easily.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you wish to remove Snip and Sketch, you can do that in Start, Settings, Apps and then click on uninstall Snip 'n Sketch. Maybe releasing Print Screen once will solve the problem. I use SnagIt and do not have interference with Snip 'n Sketch.

[image]