# change printscreen hotkey from sketch to dropbox

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, print-screen

When I press prtsc on my win 10 laptop it opens snip and sketch. Is there any way to change it and assign my prtsc button to dropbox? thanks in advance!
I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1547336/want-to-remove-snip-and-sketch-from-printscreen-key) but I don't want to uninstall snip and sketch, just change the hotkey..

Comment: Easier to let Microsoft have the key they want and use a different key for Dropbox.  That is what I do.

Comment: I was just curious. It can't be that difficult so no one can solve it.. I ll probably end doing the same, but I thought I should ask first! (so much easier to just have prtsc for greensoft or dropbox etc instead for sketch!)

Comment: There may be third party software to do this (Auto HotKey?) but my preference is to adjust non-Microsoft software.